# Laravel Passport - command not defined

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I've been stuggeling with this problem now for days: Installting Laravel passport. I did all accoring to the tutorial. What I did

```
composer require laravel/passport
```

Added `Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider::class,` to the `config/app.php`

run `php artisan migrate` and then `php artisan passport:install`
The crasy thing is this works on my local machine. But when I upload this to my webspace via ftp and run `php artisan passport:install` it gets me this Error:

```
Uncaught exception - 'There are no commands defined in the "passport" namespace.'
```

Full error (see on [pastbin](https://pastebin.com/1e2t31R5))

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException' with message 'There are no commands defined in the "passport" namespace.' in /mnt/web102/d0/25/58432925/htdocs/www/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:533
Stack trace:
#0 /mnt/web102/d0/25/58432925/htdocs/www/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(565): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->findNamespace('passport')
#1 /mnt/web102/d0/25/58432925/htdocs/www/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(204): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->find('passport:instal...')
#2 /mnt/web102/d0/25/58432925/htdocs/www/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(130): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#3 /mnt/web102/d0/25/58432925/htdocs/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(122): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Comp in /mnt/web102/d0/25/58432925/htdocs/www/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php on line 533
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException' with message 'There are no commands defined in the "passport" namespace.' in /mnt/web102/d0/25/58432925/htdocs/www/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:533
Stack trace:
#0 /mnt/web102/d0/25/58432925/htdocs/www/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(565): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->findNamespace('passport')
#1 /mnt/web102/d0/25/58432925/htdocs/www/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(204): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->find('passport:instal...')
#2 /mnt/web102/d0/25/58432925/htdocs/www/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(130): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#3 /mnt/web102/d0/25/58432925/htdocs/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(122): Symfony\Component\Consol in /mnt/web102/d0/25/58432925/htdocs/www/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php on line 533
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.30
Content-type: text/html
```

What I did.

1. uploaded all my code without the ./vendor and composer.lock
2. (uploaded the server .env)
3. `php composer.phar clearcace`
4. `php composer.phar update`
5. `php artisan cache:clear`
6. `php artisan config:cache`
7. `php artisan migrate`
8. `php artisan passport:install`

And then the error happens...

If did `php composer.phar require laravel/passport` and can see via ftp that in the /vendor/laravel/ the passport folder is there!

Comment: Are you sure that you've added `Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider::class` to `providers` array? Looks like it's the only thing you could do wrong.

Comment: I did, I did, hundret times check that. It runs on my local machine... so there must something break on the server

Comment: What's the output of `php artisan` then?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/FGb9LE04

Comment: on my local machine there is the passport command listed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run on shared hosting try

> export APP_RUNNING_IN_CONSOLE=true

After that you can run `php artisan passport:install`

Laravel's runningInConsole method check if that environment is set or the output `php_sapi_name()` is *cli* or *phpdbg*. At a shared host it can be *cgi-fcgi*

Answer (score 3):

What I have done to do solve the problem!

Inside `\vendor\laravel\passport\src\PassportServiceProvider.php` if deleted the

```
if ($this->app->runningInConsole()) {
```

in line 37. After uploading this to my webspace if could have full use of `laravel:passport`
Thanks for all the other help!

Comment: Can you please explain how it works?
it is working thats true but want to understand this.
thanks alot!!!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have problem that passport not installed, if you are working via FTP do these steps:

1. Upload your code without vendor and composer.lock
2. Make sure that .env exist or fill 'key' in app.php
3. Run composer dumpautoload
4. Run this command composer update --no-scripts
5. Try to run php artisan just to list all commands, if you got all commands then you can run php artisan passport:install

Hope this will work.

Comment: I wil check this out now

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using:

> php artisan config:clear

Instead of config:cache.
It seems to have worked for me, which makes sense as you register the passport class in config/app.

Clearing all the cache also fixed me not being able to use "artisan migrate", where it previously said "nothing to migrate". The migrations don't seem to appear in database/migrations.

Comment: hm didn't helped

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i it worked after i did this

Composer update
php artisan config:cache
php artisan migrate
php artisan passport:install